# Should famous questions stay around?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-delete

In the reopen queue, I came across [What tools to automatically inline CSS style to create email HTML code? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code):

Quoting to make sure content stays visible, even when that question might get deleted:

> When you take a look at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ you learn that you need to embed inline styles in your HTML, in order for your email to be read in any mail client. Do you know any tools or script to automatically convert an HTML file with a declared in to an HTML file with only inline CCS style attributes ? Edit: Any Javascript solution ( ie: http://www.robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/ ) ? With jQuery ?

Thing is: currently, this obviously off-topic question has 109 upvotes. It was closed, but there are already two re-open requests (and one 1 delete requests).

I don't dare to click on "leave closed"; as I already had a wrong test today; and I am really wondering if this isn't a test one again.

( I would rather add a delete vote; but I already used all of them today).

So, questions:

- what would be the correct action here?
- out of curiosity: why would anybody ask to re-open something like this? Are there any statistics on high-votes-but-deleted questions?

Comment: There's a new comment on your linked post that somewhat implies "it helped me, so I'll reopen it". As for the 2nd vote, I guess robo-reviewers? ;)

Comment: Since the question is actually closed, there's no way it'd be used as an audit as an example of a question that should be open.  I'm rather confident it's not an audit at all; the post doesn't look like it meets the criteria for either a known good or a known bad audit.

Comment: It works, cool ... the high flyer has +2490. Nice.

Comment: @Servy Too bad. It is not showing up in the queue again fro me ... but whatever; I will check tomorrow if it is still around ;-)

Comment: Interesting, it's a dupe target, but there's a deletion vote.  Wonder how that happened.

Comment: @Will How do you see that?

Comment: @Will [block on delete voting dupe targets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/165773) was implemented in 2015, about 2 years after this question was closed (in 2013). Apparently someone voted delete before the block was there (watching the garbage answers in there I wonder why there was only one delete vote)

Comment: This question *really* isn't that famous.

Comment: It is off-topic, so the right decision is to let the post closed because, especially here on StackOverflow, the number of upvotes does not necessarily reflect a good quality post